# Background image under avatar Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to put a background image under an avatar which is in circle. I can add a background color to this code, but I need to add some image. So how I can implement this in my code?

```
var avatarImage = new CircleImage
{
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
    WidthRequest = Device.OnPlatform(220, 220, 300),
    HeightRequest = Device.OnPlatform(220, 220, 300),
    Source = ImageSource.FromFile("about_background.png"),
};

avatarLayout.Children.Add(avatarImage);
```

Background like on this image:[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtVnC.jpg)

Comment: Is `avatarLayout` a `StackLayout`?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, like this?

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var stack = new StackLayout();

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.HeightRequest = 400;
        grid.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        var bgrImg = new Image();
        bgrImg.Aspect = Aspect.Fill;
        bgrImg.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/1609887_238338919678588_860551778_n.jpg?oh=469b60dbef099ca197f088f97e5e1436&oe=5852DA43"));

        var img = new Image();
        img.VerticalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Center, false);
        img.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/1622680_238338033012010_860901821_n.jpg?oh=a216ba790ec4f771c7b9488fc819ed80&oe=5814192E"));

        grid.Children.Add(bgrImg, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(img);

        Grid.SetRowSpan(img, 2);

        stack.Children.Add(grid);

        Content = stack;
    }
```

Just wait some time until background image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, it is my solution, you save my time